# How to rewriting url to split the last path by "dot" and redirect to a query string by splitted items?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I have a whois form that works with get query string and make results.

I want to redirect url from:

> mysite.com/domain/google.com

to

> mysite.com/domain?sld=google&tld=com

Thanks

Comment: Please show you .htaccess code

Comment: It's default of wordpress and have no special code.

Comment: `# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

Answer (score 0):

In .htacees
For example try this --

```
Redirect /domain/google.com /domain?sld=google&tld=com
```

OR

Try this using through jquery for using any url

```
var baseurl = "mysite.com/domain/";
var a = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();
var name = a.split(".")[0];
var name1 = a.split(".")[1];
alert(name);
alert(name1);
alert(baseurl+'?sld='+name+'&tld='+name1);
window.open(baseurl+'?sld='+name+'&tld='+name1);
```

Hope it will work for you

Comment: Thank bro. But google.com was a sample.
I want it works with any url.

Comment: @MohammadJ :  Yes you can use for any url

Comment: I mean any random url that user may search.

Comment: @MohammadJ : I Update my answer please check